# unsigned transactions not supported - web3, infura, @ethereumjs/tx

Tags: web3js, transactions, infura, ethereumjs-tx, sendsignedtransaction

I am working on sending signed transactions using web3, @ethereumjs/tx, and infura. However, I am getting an error "unsigned transactions not supported".

Here my code, [credit](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/c8b30db96d7532e15f85fcfe72ac719c):

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const Tx = require('@ethereumjs/tx').Transaction

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID'))

const addressFrom = '0x210490505e07cB9762017288e4729d0f15xxxxxx';
const Key = 'PRIVATE_KEY';
privateKey = Buffer.from(Key, 'hex');
const addressTo = '0x8035f72510907Fe3EE05b4dF439E5D0d977xxxxx';

const txData = {
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2500000000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(10e9), // 10 Gwei
  from: addressFrom,
  to: addressTo,
  //chainId: 4,
  value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('123', 'wei'))
}

const sendRawTransaction = txData =>
  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(txCount => {
    const newNonce = web3.utils.toHex(txCount)
    const transaction = new Tx({ ...txData, nonce: newNonce }, { chain: 'rinkeby' })
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx, function(err, hash) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Tx Hash:' + hash);
      }else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  })

sendRawTransaction(txData)
```

Error:

```
Error: Returned error: transaction could not be decoded: unsigned transactions not supported
at Object.ErrorResponse (/PATH/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
at /PATH/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:303:36
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/PATH/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/PATH/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/PATH/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/PATH/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/PATH/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:381:22)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1307:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  data: null
}
```

Things that I tried:

- Making data not null
- Adding 'chainId: 4' in transaction
- Double checked if my private key is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code :

1. Replace `const Tx = require('@ethereumjs/tx').Transaction` by `const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction` (as in the [link](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/c8b30db96d7532e15f85fcfe72ac719c) you provided).

You are currently using the [2.x](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) version of `ethereumjs-tx` which should not be confused with the [3.x](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx) (renamed to `@ethereumjs/tx`) as there are breaking changes.

2. Your gas limit is way too high (`2500000000`)

The block gas limit is limited to `10000000` on the Rinkeby network, your transaction `gasLimit` must therefore not exceed this quantity.
For a simple transfer between two EOAs (with no additional data) you can put `21000` as the gas limit.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after making both the changes.

Comment: what's the version of ethereumjs-tx in package.json ?

Comment: "ethereumjs-tx": "^2.1.2" -- from package.json

Comment: Your code works with me with the 2 changes, ethereumjs-tx "^2.1.2" and web3 "^1.2.2".  If you still have the issue I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: It works for me as well. I updated my web3.

Comment: Can you share why this happens and what changes should I make if I have to get with working with '@ethereumjs/tx'?

Comment: @RupanshuYadav Unfortunately I am not yet familiar with the 3.x version. You could try the examples from their doc : https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx. Also feel free to ask a new question if you encounter any new problems.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction; // require module for creating transaction object
const Web3 = require("web3"); // require the web3 module to interact with the blockchain and smartcontracts on blockchains
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

// Creating a transaction
// Build the transaction object
// If it is a mainnet, sign the transaction
// Deploy or send seralised Transaction to the blockchain
dotenv.config();
// connecting to blockchain testnet rinkeby
const w3 = new Web3(
  "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/aafb8adb2afe49d7bfb057d4bbe3ec8c"
);

// public address to send ether
const addr1 = "0x2f92B9e10D44E9b3554b9a0A9EeB258B7107328c";
const addr2 = "0xbe875509Afaaf0Dc322B8D7db11EFe2d8F3F6bB7";

// private address to sign contract
const private_key = Buffer.from(process.env.Private_Key, "hex"); // addr1 private key

// transaction object
// We are sending 1 ether from our account to another account, with a gasPrice of 10 gwei and Limit of 21000

w3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr1, (err, transactionCount) => {
  const transaction_Object = {
    to: addr2,
    gasPrice: w3.utils.toHex(w3.utils.toWei("10", "gwei")),
    gasLimit: w3.utils.toHex(21000),
    nonce: w3.utils.toHex(transactionCount),
    value: w3.utils.toHex(w3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether")),
  };

  // Signing the transaction
  const tx = new Tx(transaction_Object, { chain: "rinkeby" }); // creating a new transactrion object to sign
  tx.sign(private_key); // sign the transaction using the private key

  //   Send signed transactiont to the blockchain
  const sTx = tx.serialize();
  const rawTransaction = "0x" + sTx.toString("hex");

  w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction, (err, hash) => {
    console.log("TxHash:" + hash);
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've finally found the answer everybody is looking for!

What's breaking with the previous implementation of `ethereumjs-tx` is that the signed data is no longer added to the transaction instance. It means it's just present during the `.sign` line, it is not reachable after.

A fix regarding your implementation, that I've tested, would consist of just compacting the sign and the serialization on one line:
`const serializedTx = transaction.sign(privateKey).serialize().toString('hex')`

Works perfectly with @ethereumjs/tx^3.5.2